# Persisting state of nested dynamic controls

Tags: c#

I have a page where I create many dynamic controls, the controls are deeply nested. I have no idea how to maintain/persist their value/state. The controls are created upon dropdown value changed event:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // Here I create radio button and add them
    RadioButton rd = new RadioButton();

    rd.id = "rd" + i;

    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        // Here I create textbox and add them to page
        TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
        tbx.id = "tbx" + j + i;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the state or value of these controls?

Comment: You have to rebuild them again very early on in the page lifecycle (try Init)